# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object for Google Calendar XML

Tags: php, web

I need some help with this code. It was running perfectly up until a couple of weeks ago.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$cache_time = 3600*12;

$feedRegular = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/invernesscalvary.com_fipcro22aiul8uaa2hg80h6gmc%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?orderby=starttime&singleevents=true&futureevents=true&max-results=999&sortorder=a";
$feedFeature = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/invernesscalvary.com_8ohrv5fhqf7o2r9jhgsr2q2764%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?orderby=starttime&singleevents=true&futureevents=true&max-results=3&sortorder=a";

$cache_file_reg = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/gcal.xml';
$timedif_reg = @(time() - filemtime($cache_file_reg));
$xmlRegular = "";

if (file_exists($cache_file_reg) && $timedif_reg < $cache_time) {
    $str_reg = file_get_contents($cache_file_reg);
    $xmlRegular = simplexml_load_string($str_reg);
    } else {
    $xmlRegular = simplexml_load_file($feedRegular);
    if ($f_reg = fopen($cache_file_reg, 'w')) {
        $str_reg = $xmlRegular->asXML();
        fwrite ($f_reg, $str_reg, strlen($str_reg));
        fclose($f_reg);
    } else { echo "<p>Can't write to the cache.</p>"; }
}

$xmlRegular->asXML();

$cache_file_fea = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/gcal_featured.xml';
$timedif_fea = @(time() - filemtime($cache_file_fea));
$xmlFeature = "";

if (file_exists($cache_file_fea) && $timedif_fea < $cache_time) {
    $str_fea = file_get_contents($cache_file_fea);
    $xmlFeature = simplexml_load_string($str_fea);
} else {
    $xmlFeature = simplexml_load_file($feedFeature);
    if ($f_fea = fopen($cache_file_fea, 'w')) {
        $str_fea = $xmlFeature->asXML();
        fwrite ($f_fea, $str_fea, strlen($str_fea));
        fclose($f_fea);
    } else { echo "<p>Can't write to the cache.</p>"; }
}

if (is_object($xmlFeature)) {
    $xmlFeature->asXML();
}

$n = 0;

foreach ($xmlRegular->entry as $entry) {
    $n++;
    $ns_gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

    $eDate = date("M", strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime));
    $eDay = date("j", strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime));
    $eTime = date("g:ia", strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime));

    $eLink = date("Y/m", strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime));

    $title = str_replace(" & ", " &amp; ", $entry->title);
    $where = $ns_gd->where->attributes()->valueString;

                        $link = $entry->link->attributes()->href;
    echo "<li>\n";
    echo "<span class=\"eDate\">$eDate <span class=\"eDay\">$eDay</span> @ $eTime</span><a rel=\"$eLink\" title=\"@ $where\" href=\"#\">";
    echo "<p class=\"eTitle\">$title</p></a>\n";
    echo "</li>\n\n";
    if($n == 3) break;
}

?>
```

**FIXED** Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object in /home/calvary/public_html/index.php on line 83

**FIXED** If I do a var_dump($xmlRegular) after the simplexml_load_string($str_reg) I get a boolean false.

**UPDATE** `Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in /home/calvary/public_html/index.php.new on line 132` now shows up twice for each line 132, 133, 134, 136, and 139 which are the lines starting with $eDate $eDay $eTime $eLink and $where.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than post code to an external source, please trim the code to only the most relevant parts needed to illustrate your issue and post it here. Highlight the code and use the editor toolbar `{}` button or `ctl-k` to format it as a code block, which will get automatic syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the $xmlRegular variable is not an object. Likely, it's a Boolean with a false value. This is because the simplexml_load_string or simplexml_load_file is failing to return an object. I believe the most probable reason would be simplexml_load_file does not have read permissions or cannot find the file.

I'd recommend var_dump'ing a value and then running an 'exit;' to see what the value at that point is. This way you can see which value is incorrect.

Please let us know if you make any progress on this and I'd be happy to provide more input!

**EDIT: Going directly to the URL you are using ($feedRegular) I get a Forbidden 403 error. This would cause your $xmlRegular to be false instead of an object.**

Comment: Just updated the calendar link and the question, thanks

Comment: Hey Alexander! If your update is true, it seems that the object is attempting to generate an object from a cache file on your system. Can you var_dump() both $cache_file_reg and $str_reg and post the results? This is where the problem lies, that string can not be converted to an XML object.

Comment: Also, two thoughts. 1, you could probably find out a lot more about why this is not working using the error log. 2, I would appreciate an upvote if you're finding my information helpful.

Comment: If I run it in a browser I get
`string(40) "/home/calvary/public_html/cache/gcal.xml"` for $cache_file_reg
`string(0) ""` for $str_reg

Comment: If I ssh into the server and do php index.php I get `var_dump($cache_file_reg); string(14) "/cache/gcal.xml" var_dump($str_reg); string(0) ""`

Comment: Ok, then it is clear that file_get_contents is not working. This is likely because of server permissions or restrictions. If you connect to the server and go to {/home/calvary/public_html/cache/} is there a file called gcal.xml? If there is, what are the permissions set to? Try setting this file to 0777 (temporarily, should be more secure, at least 0775) to see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: I did chmod 0777 to gcal.xml and nothing changed. So, I double checked the XML file (opens great in Firefox). Then right before `$xmlRegular->asXML();` I put a var_dump($f_reg) hoping to get a string. It returned NULL.

Comment: $f_reg is only defined in the bottom half of the IF statement. In your question it says that simplexml_load_string() is returning false, which is in the top half of your IF statement. Can you var dump different things in each section of the IF statement and determine which one is firing in this case? Perhaps var_dump($str_reg); in the top half and var_dump($feedRegular); in the bottom? This way we can confirm both paths are correct and we know which one is actually not able to be loaded by the PHP.

Comment: `if (file_exists($cache_file_reg) && $timedif_reg < $cache_time) { $str_reg = file_get_contents($cache_file_reg); var_dump($str_reg); exit();` returns string(0) "". If I var_dump the $xmlRegular right below, I get bool(false). The statement never makes it to the else{} clause.

Comment: Interesting that the file_get_contents on a local file is returning "" and not false. It should return false on a failure. Can you open the file and see if it has any content? If it is empty, try deleting it.